# Bayesian mixed ANOVA

Tags: bayesian, anova, hierarchical-bayesian

I am analysing temperature series measured by different sensors under different conditions controlled by three experimental factors. I am interested to learn how much of the variability in the measured temperatures is explained by these factors.

This is a sketch of my sample design:

[image: Example]

My doubt is that one of the levels of Factor 2 (Lv1 in the picture) has 1 level of Factor 3 that the other 2 levels of Factor 2 do not have and vice versa. This is due to the impossibility to apply Lv2-3 of Factor 3 to Lv1 of Factor 2 and vice versa.

I would like to perform a hierarchical Bayesian ANOVA, but my attempts to do it failed until now. However also a frequentist ANOVA is ok at this stage.

Any suggestions on how to perform it in R or JAGS?